# XSLT: 'xsl:value-of' within an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSL transformation:

```
<xsl:for-each select="refsect1[@id = 'seealso']/para/citerefentry">
  /// <seealso cref=""/>
  <xsl:value-of select="refentrytitle" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I place the value of *refentrytitle* in the cref attribute of the *seealso* tag in the template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand how place the value of refentrytitle in the cref
>   attribute of the seealso tag in the template.

Just put your expression within curly brackets (this is called [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) or simply AVT syntax) like this:

```
<seealso cref="{refentrytitle}"/>
```

Comment: @Luca: Sure, e.g. `{string-length(refentrytitle)}`. In general you can use XPath functions just like in `xsl:value-of select`.

Comment: This is the more compact and flexible way to achieve the result. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="refsect1[@id = 'seealso']/para/citerefentry">
  /// <xsl:element name="seealso">
    <xsl:attribute name="cref">
      <xsl:value-of select="refentrytitle" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or you could probably just do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="refsect1[@id = 'seealso']/para/citerefentry">
  /// <seealso cref="{refentrytitle}" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Is it possible to force the short tag *<seealso/>*?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you get to control that with the former, i.e. it might just be down to what the XSLT processor decides.